# how to get pictures off the phone (running 5.1.1)?

Tags: macos, ios

So my dad left behind his old phone so my son can use it as a music player. It's currently running 5.1.1.

There are several albums and one of them are pictures of our family. I want to get them off the the device  but when I connected the device to my MBPr (running Yosemite) and selected the phone inside "Image Capture", not all photos are showing. There's easily around 500+ photos inside various albums but I can only 29 pictures are showing which are all from an album called "Saved Photos".

Any ideas on how to get it off the device? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

- set up email on the iPhone and mail the photos to yourself (might be kind of cumbersome with iOS 5 though)
- install any third party app allowing photo upload (e.g. Dropbox or Flickr) on the iPhone and upload all photos to it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the Photo's app on Yosemite works on iOS 5.

What you can do is connect the iPhone to your mac and fire up the Photo's app. Then select the photo's you want and drag them a folder where you want them saved.

If Photo's does not work, you could update the iPhone to the latest iOS version to use the Photo's app on OS X Yosemite. When you to this, make sure you make a backup first of the iPhone and you have the Apple ID email and password.

Answer (score -1):

If the photos were put on to the phone by syncing them from iTunes, and/or the photos are not in the "camera roll", you won't be able to import them conventionally.

If you get the photos into the camera roll you should be able to import them.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201302

Also give the photos app a try instead of image capture (the OSX photos app)

Judging off the pictures, the software below seems like it might help. But given the fact that all you want is these photos, it probably makes more sense to email them or upload them to dropbox as someone else suggested.

https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/ There seems to be a pc version as well called phonetopc

Comment: Often times you first have to understand why theres a problem in the first place before you can figure out how to solve it, or if it can be solved to begin with.

Theres two stock app that deal with photos on the iPhone, one is called photos, and the other is called camera (which as far as i know contains the "camera roll"). Im suggesting the possibility that the photos he wants are in photos rather than the camera roll, because he didn't specify where they were.

Comment: I put those sentences there because he didn't explicitly say anything that would indicate those aren't the problems.


Had either of those been the problem, the solutions would be clear, and he'd have been helped.